# How to avoid JS code into an input?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have an input text that shows a personal message in the user's profile. This input is not validated, so the user can introduce anything. As you can see, the user can set a Script tag with an alert or a redirect.

How can avoid this with PHP?

Thanks.

Comment: You cannot avoid the user entering such things, obviously. You might try to filter them, but you won't succeed. What you have to do is precisely escape the content when handing it out again, so that it is _not_ interpreted by the receiving client, but shown as text only. That is called "escaping".

Answer (score 1):

Use `htmlspecialchars()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php - this will prevent any HTML code (including `<script>` tags) from being processed by the browser when the input is displayed.

Comment: maybe he want to allow some tags..?